# Easiest way to get minterms from a SOP Boolean expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

So far, I've come across problems were I need to get the list of the minterms in a truthtable from a SOP Boolean expression. For example;
[image]

They way I've tackled these problems was to convert the expression into a K-map, and get the minterms from there. I wonder though if there's an easier or simpler way to get the minterms? I've searched for this but nothing really came up.

Comment: Easier would be to use a software doing it for you.

Comment: What's easier than converting it to a K-map?

Comment: You can master Boolean algebra and find it easier.